# dart, less and @import: FileError: 'file.less' not found

Tags: import, dart, less

I'm developing a web application in dart, and I have two `.less` files in the same directory, and I would like to import one file from another:

```
/* file1.less */
@red-color: red;
@blue-color: blue;

/* file2.less */
@import 'file1';
background {
    background-color: @red-color;
}
```

But when I run `pub server` it prints the following error:

```
FileError: 'file1.less' wasn't found. Tried - file.less in - on line 1, column 1:
1 @import 'file1';
..^
2
```

Is that a bug? Am I using the @import directive in a wrong way?

Comment: I assume you use a less transformer package. Which one? How does your `pubspec.yaml` look like?

Comment: Yes. I have defined a transformer in pubspec.yaml (transformers: - less_dart).

Comment: Can you please try adding `relativeUrls: true` to the transformer config. See the readme of the less_dart package for details how to pass options.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just realized that less do not use relative paths by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default less do not use relative paths. So we must indicate the absolute uri. For example:

```
/* absolute path to file1.less */
@import 'web/styles/file1';
```

Or if we want to import a file from our package:

```
/* absolute path to file1.less */
@import 'packages/<project_name>/<path/to>/file1';
```